# How to use css styling in html with multiple directories?

Tags: python, html, css, google-app-engine

I'm trying to make a simple webapp using Google Appengine with Python, HTML, and CSS. I know that to put a .css styling from separate file into html one should use a link tag, however I can't seem to get it to work. Here is the general directory config:

Main
├── app.yaml
├── files.py
├── Folder
│   ├── files.py
│   ├── Templates
│   │   ├── form.html
│   ├── Static
│   │   ├── style.css

"form.html" contains the layout and "style.css" contains styling. I tried putting in the code from "style.css" directly into "form.html" with a style tag and it worked, however when I use the link tag in the head section of the html file it doesn't work. Here is what link tags I tried so far:

```
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Static/style.css">
    <title> ... </title>
</head>
```

or

```
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Folder/Static/style.css">
    <title> ... </title>
</head>
```

or

```
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Main/Folder/Static/style.css">
    <title> ... </title>
</head>
```

None of these work, what could be a solution?

Comment: Which is the static content config (covering the `style.css` file) in your `app.yaml` file (or the respective serving rules in your app code if you're serving it dynamically)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a url handler in your app.yaml:

```
- url: /Static 
  static_dir: Static/
  secure: optional
```

I am not sure about your directory tree.  If Static is nested inside Folder, then it would be:

```
- url: /Folder/Static 
  static_dir: Folder/Static/
  secure: optional
```

Or, if Static is nested inside Folder, and you want to simplify your html links, then:

```
- url: /Static  # <== what url to handle
  static_dir: Folder/Static/  # <== where to point that url
  secure: optional
```

and you can access by:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Static/style.css">
```

Comment: Your solution is almost the right one, however I changed the href in your link to read "/Folder/Static/style.css" and it worked. Thanks for the info about the url handler!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure from your file diagram, but I think you're not referencing the CSS file properly in the link tag.

If the two files are in these spots:

Main/Folder/Templates/form.html

Main/Folder/Static/style.css

Then in the HTML, your link tag will need to be

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../Static/style.css">
```

Because relative to the form.html file, you need to back up a directory to the 'Folder' dir before you add the Static path to the end there...

In any case, generally you don't need a slash at the start of the path containing the CSS unless you are entering the absolute path all the way from the root

Comment: also concerns when on a local server as WAMP etc